# items with different background color repeatedly

Tags: css

is it possible on CSS that each item can have different colors repeatedly? for example, it have 20 items and each have 5 different bgcolors.

html like

```
<div class="item"> ... item 1 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 2 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 3 .. </div> 
...
<div class="item"> ... item 20 .. </div>
```

as I known in CSS it like

```
.item:nth-child(1){
  background-color: red;
}
.item:nth-child(2){
  background-color: blue;
}
.item:nth-child(3){
  background-color: yellow;
}
...
.item:nth-child(5){
  background-color: green;
}
```

As I have known, to make it work, I will code each `.item:nth-child(n)` and assigning different colors - that is static.

can it be done by dynamic? where I cannot longer code 20 of `.item:nth-child(n)` just assigning color? instead, CSS will assign each 5 items with different color? like color 1 is red, 2 is blue, 3 is yellow, 4 is violet, and 5 is green - then it repeats, item 6 is red again and so on.. until goes 20 will be green. The most conflict is, we can't add another class to the `div` it just the `item` class. is this theory possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```css
.item:nth-child(5n + 1) {
  background-color: red;
}

.item:nth-child(5n + 2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.item:nth-child(5n + 3) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item:nth-child(5n + 4) {
  background-color: violet;
}

.item:nth-child(5n + 5) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"> ... item 1 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 2 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 3 .. </div>
<div class="item"> ... item 4 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 5 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 6 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 7 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 8 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 9 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 10 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 11 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 12 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 13 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 14 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 15 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 16 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 17 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 18 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 19 .. </div> 
<div class="item"> ... item 20 .. </div>
```

The point is to define after how many `div`'s you want the pattern to repeat, this is the first number or `5n`, then you set their order of appearance with the numbers `+1` to `+5`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, take a look at `functional notation` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

```css
.item:nth-child(3n) {
  color: red;
}

.item:nth-child(3n+1) {
  color: blue;
}

.item:nth-child(3n+2) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="item"> ... item 1 .. </div> 
  <div class="item"> ... item 2 .. </div> 
  <div class="item"> ... item 3 .. </div> 
  <div class="item"> ... item 4 .. </div> 
  <div class="item"> ... item 5 .. </div> 
  <div class="item"> ... item 6 .. </div>
</div>
```